# CSS inline / block issue with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

http://erickochphoto.com/avejoe/?page_id=14 is rendering fine in FF and IE, but fails in chrome.

I am using clear: both display: block / inline every where I can think of, but I am failing. Any ideas?

```
#main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 375px;
    background: url(images/paper.png) repeat-y;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#leftBackCopy
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(images/map.png) no-repeat;
    width: 122px;    
    height: 426px;
    float: left;
}
#rightBackCopy
{
    display: inline
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(images/trimCam.png) no-repeat;
    height: 195px;
    width: 122px;
    float: left;
}
#mainHolder
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1044px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
#mainHolder {
  overflow:auto;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}
```

Leave all the ither styles intact, just add the above. Worked for me, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go too far into it, but deleting this portion of your HTML seems to fix the problem and put things in line (in Chrome):

```
<div class="menu"><ul><li ><a href="http://erickochphoto.com/avejoe/" title="Home">Home</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-14 current_page_item"><a href="http://erickochphoto.com/avejoe/?page_id=14" title="Test">Test</a></li></ul></div>
```

So, perhaps theres conflict within the CSS regarding the menu class or its unordered list.